# necessity of mining while doing transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, web3j, java

While doing any transaction in private network, is it necessary for one node to keep on mining?.

I was trying to implement to deploy smart contract and transact in ethereum private network with the help of web3j java library. When there was no mining happening, my java transaction code was error out and it was saying transaction exceeds time limit of 600 seconds. But when I started mining and run the program, it was successful. But because of these two process, my system became very slow.

What is the reason behind these scenario? Any suggestion?

Comment: The tnx was only confirmed when it was include in a block sealing; then you need to start mining.

For private chain, you can have another option to use Clique POA consensus then your system will be free without running ton of calculation for PoW

Comment: @HaĐANG Will you refer some docs from where I can learn how to work with PoA. And please write your comment as answer if it is a final one.

Comment: You can refer to this; it already implemented in ethereum code base

https://medium.com/@collin.cusce/using-puppeth-to-manually-create-an-ethereum-proof-of-authority-clique-network-on-aws-ae0d7c906cce

Comment: @HaĐANG this one is for Linux OS. Will it work on windows OS?

Comment: Yes, It works for windows OS also